# How can I redirect to destination after authentication interruption? Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a MEAN application that is working fine. I'm using Passport to authenticate with jwt which I saved on mongo database and use localStorage for session awareness.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngStorage',
'ngRoute',
'ngResource',
'angular.filter',
'ngMaterial',
'ui.bootstrap'
]).run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) {
        AuthService.getUserStatus()
            .then(function(){
                if (next.access.restricted && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){

                    $location.path('/login');
                    $route.reload();
                } else {
                    var permissions = next.permissions
                    if (permissions.indexOf(AuthService.myRoleIs()) == -1) {
                        $location.path("/");
                        $route.reload();
                        swal("Restrict Access!", "Please contact admin.", "error");

                    }
                }
            });
    });
})


.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            access: {restricted: true},
            permissions: ['Operator','Supervisor', 'Admin','Viewer']
        }).
        when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl',
            access: {restricted: true},
            permissions: ['Admin']
        }).
        when('/me', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/me.html',
            controller: 'MeCtrl',
            access: {restricted: true},
            permissions: ['Operator','Supervisor','Admin','Viewer']
        }).

otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
        access: {restricted: false}
    })



$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function($q, $location, $localStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($localStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = $localStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function(response) {
                if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/login');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);

}
```

])

I want that whenever an authentication take place the user is able to continue to destination after verification. Right now, the user is returned to home directory.

Comment: what is the destination!?

Comment: Destination is given on "next" in the '$routeChangeStart' section.

Comment: then use `$location.path(next);` instead of `$location.path("/");`